# Change Youtube Flutter Flags

Tags: flutter, flags, youtube-player-flutter

Is there a way to change the Youtube flutter Flags after first init.

I am trying to make it so that upon clicking a button to a new video it changes video and then also sets the Flags startAt and endAt to my chosen ints.

However `controller.flags.startAt` and the end at come up with the error "can't be used as a setter because it's final.

```js
_ytController = YoutubePlayerController(
        initialVideoId: YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(defaultStream)!,
        flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
          mute: false,
          loop: true,
          autoPlay: true,
        ));
        
        
        _ytController.startAt = 20; //doesn't allow due to final
        _ytController.endAt = 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass them within the YoutubePlayerController inside of a YoutubePlayerParams() object. Set it after you set flags to something like this:

```
flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(...),
params: YoutubePlayerParams(startAt: 20, endAt: 30)
```

Comment: This is for a different Package. Im using Youtube_player. This seems to be for Youtube_player_iframe. Also, i want to be able to put a variable in the startAt and endAt field and when the new video is player for it to start and end at those times.

Comment: No, it's for youtube_player_flutter. I'm not seeing any published packages for youtube_player, so I suspect you're also using this package. Also, just replace the numbers with your variables and you're good.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. You use the controller.Load and within there after you put in the YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(url) then you can set your start and End time.